# Are there any good examples of how to take a screenshot in selenium webdriver C#, then crop and save the image?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, screenshot, crop

I've been searching for some good examples of how to take a screenshot using ITakesScreenshot in Selenium Webdriver in C#, then to crop the image using the elements dimensions and then saving this new image. With no such luck have I found any in C#.

I have this method at the moment but every so often I get a Out of Memory exception when used in a test. It fails on the line where it tries to crop.

```
public void TakeScreenShotOfElement(IWebDriver _driver, string rootpath, string imgName, string element2)
    {

            string element3 = element2;
            var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(element3));
            Byte[] ba = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            var ss = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(ba));

            var crop = new Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);

            //create a new image by cropping the original screenshot
            Bitmap image2 = ss.Clone(crop, ss.PixelFormat);


            if (!Directory.Exists(rootpath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rootpath);
            }
            image2.Save(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.png", rootpath, imgName), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the objects you're creating are `IDisposable`. You need to make sure `Dispose()` gets called on them. As it stands they're not releasing the memory they've claimed, which is why you get the exceptions.

The easiest way to make sure these items get disposed is to wrap each of them in a `using` block.